# Code deploy error

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment

Error CodeUnknownError

Script Name

```
Message: No such file or directory - /opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/a449172f-ee92-4a07-b4eb-04c90047873b/d-URYKGM6UG/deployment-archive/appspec.yml
```

Log Tail

Can someone help me in figuring out what could be the issue?

Comment: Could you post your appspec.yml for review?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your deployment has an error in the appspec.yml file, or the file is not at the root level of the archive.

Please double check the file location, and also check for typos, or invalid paths.  Those types of problems can produce these errors.

Comment: Find below contents of my appSpec.yml-

Comment: <code>version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
   - source: /
     destination: /var/www/html
permissions:
   - object: /var/www/html
     pattern: "**"
     owner: apache
     group: apache
     mode: 755
     type:
       - file
hooks:
   BeforeInstall:
    - location: Scripts/installapache.sh
      runas: root
    - location: Scripts/startapache.sh
      runas: root
   AfterInstall:
    - location: Scripts/restartapache.sh
      runas: root</code>

Comment: File is at root level only.

Answer (score 0):

```html
    version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
   - source: /
     destination: /var/www/html
permissions:
   - object: /var/www/html
     pattern: "**"
     owner: apache
     group: apache
     mode: 755
     type:
       - file
hooks:
   BeforeInstall:
    - location: Scripts/installapache.sh
      runas: root
    - location: Scripts/startapache.sh
      runas: root
   AfterInstall:
    - location: Scripts/restartapache.sh
      runas: root
```